# String formating in python or Java

Tags: java, python

Input:

```
Flipkart site india ecommerce best   **_-Replacement array_**


{} is {4} online {3} shopping {} in {}    **_-positional argument array_**
```

Output

```
Flipkart is best online ecommerce shopping site in India
```

Explanation-

**If there is number inside curly braces,print element of replacement array at that index, if that index exists otherwise print whatever is inside curly braces(Note-there may be word inside braces as well, in that case simply print that word)

**If there is nothing inside curly braces,number those as 0,1,2… from left to right and accordingly replace with corresponding element of replacement array

```
a=list(input().split())
b=list(input().split())
my(a,b)
def my(a1,b1):
    c=0
    a2=[]
    for i in range(len(b1)):
        if b1[i]=='{}':
            a2.append(a1[c]+" ")
            print(a2)
            c+=1
        elif b1[i]=='{':
            d=b[i][1]-'0'
            a2.append(a1[d]+" ")
            print(a2)
        else:
            a2.append(b1[i]+" ")
            print(a2)
    return a2
```

**This is what i have done, but elif part isn't working. Kindly Help me out!!**

I want to develop a pattern  matcher such that it can identify curly braces({}) and the number in it. But can't make it properly

Comment: You should use `startswith()`

Answer (score 0):

In python you can use the `format` command quite easily.

```
'{} {}'.format('one', 'two')
```

It will read in order so you can Access the index of your list like so .

```
'{} {}'.format(list[3], list[4])
```

Or any order you like.